# Google Maps API v3 Hiding and showing a circle bound to a marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have successfully bound a circle to my marker using google map api v3.  I know this because if I make the marker dragable the circle moves as well.

How can I refer to the circle if the marker is clicked.  I need to show the circle if not visible or vice-versa.

Here is the code to create the marker and circle

```
var markerOptions = {
title: title,
icon: markerImage,
shadow: markerShadow,
position: latlng,
map: map
}
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);   
// Add a Circle overlay to the map.
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
map: map,
radius: 50*1609.34,// 50 MI
visible: false
});
//circle.bindTo('map', marker);
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

I found an answer on stackoverflow that led me to think I needed to do the rem'd out map binding as well the center binding, but that did not work.

Here is my click event for the marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
var infowindowOptions = {
content: html
 }
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infowindowOptions);
cm_setInfowindow(infowindow);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
marker.setIcon(markerImageOut);
marker.circle({visible: true});
```

Any ideas.  I need to interact with the bound circle of the marker that was just clicked or moused over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to make the circle a property of the marker (like ._myCircle), reference it in the click handler as marker._myCircle.

Add the circle as the _myCircle property of marker:

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 50*1609.34,// 50 MI
  visible: false
});
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
marker._myCircle = circle;
```

To toggle it use something like (not tested):

```
if(marker._myCircle.getMap() != null) marker._myCircle.setMap(null);
else marker._myCircle.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  How do I make the circle a property of the marker?

Comment: There is an example in my answer (marker._myCircle is "a property of the marker").  Does it not work for you?

Comment: Forgive me but I'm just starting with this api and am not familiar with the object model.  How do I set market._myCircle equal to the circle I created thats center is bound to the marker we are speaking of.  In other words, what is the JS code that creates a property for the marker that is equal to the circle I have just created?

Comment: you put me on the right track. marker._myCircle = circle worked.  Then I put a marker._mycircle.setOptions({visible: true}); in the click event.  -Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
var rad =".$this->conf['radius'] * 1000 ."; //convert km to meter
var populationOptions = {
   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 1,
   fillColor: '#FF0000',
   fillOpacity: 0.35,
   map: map,//map object
   center: new google.maps.LatLng($corr_match[0], $corr_match[1]),//center of circle
   radius: rad
};
var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
```